# How do i sort the prices of items of a txt file in ascending order?

Tags: python, project

i want to make the prices of my products from the txt file appear in an ascending order in my display.
My txt file is like this:

```
R001,Angel Eyes,Romantic,2.0,Available
R002,Hearts on Fire,Romantic,158.0,Available
R003,Purple Rush,Romantic,288.0,Available
B001,Sweet Nothings,Birthday,98.0,Available
B002,Summer Surprise, Birthday,158.0,Available
GO001,Savannah,Grand Opening,158.0,Available
GO002,The Tropics,Grand Opening,168.0,Available
C001,Tranquility,Condolence,151.0,Available
C002,Memories,Condolence,151.0,Available
A001,Garden of Hearts,Anniversary,200.0,Available
A002,Treasured Blooms,Anniversary,188.0,Available
A003,Ray of Light,Anniversary,288.0,Available
```

and ive already created a format function for it. the items have to be sorted from top, least price to below,greatest price.

so i tried writing a sort code for it like this:

```
def sort_price(products, addons):
  #sorting the price in ascending order
      infile = open("products.txt")
      sorted_products = sorted(products.items(),key=lambda item: item[1][2])
      print(sorted_products)
     format_products(products)
```

but it didn't work, it didn't sort, instead it stayed the same. do any of you know how to fix it?

Comment: Please use **code**-formatting (`{}` button) for your code and data

Comment: Please, poste [mre]. What is `products`, what is `format_products()`?

Comment: And why do you open a file that you never use?

Comment: The format_products() is another function that i made to format the txt file data in the display with appropriate spacing according to Itemcode, flower name, category, price, status.

Comment: To answer matthias its a file im gonna have to open often to make it list in the display for imaginary customers to order from since im writing a Sales Management and Inventory Management menu and submenus program where user can update or add products and also order products. The orders needs to apparantly also appear in a new txtfile everytime theyre made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a helper function to parse the file into a list of products before sorting:

```
import dataclasses
import pathlib


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Product:
  code: str
  name: str
  category: str
  price: float
  status: str


def parse_products(file_path: pathlib.Path) -> list[Product]:
  """Parses products from a file into a list of Product objects.

  The file should contain product data in the format:
  'Code,Name,Category,Price,Status' (without quotes), each on a new line.
  
  Args:
    file_path: A Path object representing the path to the csv file 
               containing product data.
  """
  with file_path.open('r') as file:
    products = []
    for line in file.readlines():
      code, name, category, price, status = line.strip().split(',')
      products.append(Product(code, name, category, float(price), status))
    return products


def main() -> None:
  products = parse_products(pathlib.Path('products.txt'))
  for p in sorted(products, key=lambda product: product.price):
    print(f'{p.code},{p.name},{p.category},{p.price},{p.status}')
    # print(','.join([str(getattr(p, attr)) for attr in p.__dataclass_fields__]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
R001,Angel Eyes,Romantic,2.0,Available
B001,Sweet Nothings,Birthday,98.0,Available
C001,Tranquility,Condolence,151.0,Available
C002,Memories,Condolence,151.0,Available
R002,Hearts on Fire,Romantic,158.0,Available
B002,Summer Surprise, Birthday,158.0,Available
GO001,Savannah,Grand Opening,158.0,Available
GO002,The Tropics,Grand Opening,168.0,Available
A002,Treasured Blooms,Anniversary,188.0,Available
A001,Garden of Hearts,Anniversary,200.0,Available
R003,Purple Rush,Romantic,288.0,Available
A003,Ray of Light,Anniversary,288.0,Available
```